# Use results from a query in another

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using Wordpress and the plugin WPForms which stores form entries in my database like so:

(Doesn't seem like the most logical / best database design to me, but I have no choice).

[image: database]

Considering the table above. I need to select the entry ID's of the rows where `meta_value` contains the word 'Houd'.

I wrote this query which does that nicely:

```
SELECT entry_id 
AS entries
FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` 
WHERE `meta_value` 
LIKE '%Houd%'
```

Now, I would need to select to get the email adresses (which is `entries_for_wpforms_field_id_8`). Where the entry_id is equal to one of the id's fetched by the query above.

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'entries_for_wpforms_field_id_8' 
AND `entry_id` = <result of other query>;
```

**How do I use the list of ID's of the previous query in my where in the other query?**

I tried using a cross-join, like so:

```
SELECT entry_id 
AS entries
FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` 
WHERE `meta_value` 
LIKE '%Houd%'
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT `meta_value`
    FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta`
    WHERE `meta_key` = 'entries_for_wpforms_field_id_8'
);
```

It resulted in a syntax error:

> Error in used syntax near 'CROSS JOIN (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` WHER' in line 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use exists

```
SELECT `meta_value`
FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` q
WHERE `meta_key` = 'entries_for_wpforms_field_id_8' and exists (
   SELECT 1
   FROM `wp_wpforms_entrymeta` qin
   WHERE `meta_value`  LIKE '%Houd%' and q.entry_id = qin.entry_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doens't work. My first query (in my post) returns a set of ID's. I need to use these in the `WHERE` of the second one.

Comment: can you check again? I made a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first hunch you could also use a self-join to do it:

```
SELECT
    t1.meta_value
FROM wp_wpforms_entrymeta AS t1
JOIN wp_wpforms_entrymeta AS t2
     ON t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id 
WHERE t1.meta_key = 'entries_for_wpforms_field_id_8'
     AND t2.meta_value LIKE '%Houd%';
```

Try it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6df40/1/0).